# Where am I going wrong while matching the time?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, time

How can I match time with what is in the `database` to the `current time` ?

This is how I have been doing till now but haven't succeeded.  There is a column named `stime` in the table that has the datatype `TIME`. It has values in `HH:mm:ss`

```
        String time = dateFormat.format(new java.sql.Time(new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()));
        int timeattr[] = new int[2];
        int i = 0;
        for(String a : time.split(":")) {
            timeattr[i] = Integer.parseInt(a);
            i++;
        }
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), timeattr[0], timeattr[1], 0);

        // QUERY 
        String hql = "from Scheduled where stime <= :now";

        List list = session.createQuery(hql).setTime("now", new java.sql.Time(gc.getTimeInMillis())).list();
        Iterator iterator = list.iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()) { // never enters the loop }
```

Comment: disregard my answer for now, but what are you actually trying to do to `stime`? are you trying to set stime to the current time and update that column in the database?

Comment: @JamesMassey I have to run a `scheduled job`

Comment: and how does that involve `stime`? what does `stime` actually represent?

Comment: @JamesMassey It is the `scheduled time`

Comment: `stime` represents the scheduled time for the job to run, and you want the job to run now? Are you using Spring Batch to control the job? If so, you can manually start a job that already exists. If you aren't using Spring Batch, this is still the wrong way to do this. What does your scheduled job involve? We need more information about the background of your application. Edit your question if you have to. Provide background on what you are trying to do (with the job), what you want to achieve, and what systems/frameworks you are currently using

Comment: @JamesMassey Yes, I want the job to run now. I am not using Spring Batch. The scheduled job is meant to `tweet`

Comment: So you are using the Twitter API? Are you using some kind of Quartz Task scheduler or something. By what mechanism are you detecting that the job needs to be run at a certain time?

Comment: @JamesMassey I am sorry but how will knowing that, answer the above question ?

Comment: @JamesMassey This is what I am failing at. I am not able to detect. May be the way I am making the comparison is wrong.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. You are trying to write a query that will detect what objects scheduled time has past the current time so you can manually kick off the job. From the way your question was phrased I thought you wanted to set `stime` to the current time so that the job would run.

Comment: @JamesMassey No, as you said I am trying to manually kick off the job and I am failing at it.

Comment: What version of hibernate are you using?

Comment: See my new answer, I'm pretty sure that should solve your problem assuming that the `Scheduled` table has an object representation. FooClass should be the object that represents `Scheduled`

Comment: Why do you extract out the time parameters from the Calendar just to put them back together into a Calendar. Why not just create a new Calendar instance for 'now'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, remove the `.setTime` call, its not doing what you think its doing.

To actually fix your problem, use the Criteria API rather than manually defining your own HQL query.

```
//Create a query that is checking columns on FooTable.
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(FooTable.class); 
//FooTable is where stime is stored. 

//Create a restriction on your query to only return records where the 'stime'
//column is less than the current system time.
criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("stime", new Time(System.currentTimeMillis()));

 //return all records in a list format.
 List list = criteria.list();
 //iterate over your list here.
```

The above code should replace everything above your iterator declaration.

If this doesn't work, can you post exceptions/stacktraces/error messages

Comment: Though I can try this method but can you please explain what is going wrong with my way of doing ?

Comment: the .setTime() method isn't used in the way you are using it. It used for something completely different. The other thing is my code is a hell of a lot more readable than what you are doing. 3 lines vs 10 with a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
String hql = "from Scheduled where stime <= CURRENT_TIME()";
```

should work without all those messy calculations.

In practice you may need to track the last time that the query was executed so that subsequent calls don't pick up the previous results:

```
String hql = "from Scheduled where stime > :last_time AND stime <= CURRENT_TIME()";
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: What happens if you execute "select * from SCHEDULED where stime <= NOW()" directly in the database?

Comment: it gives the expected result

Comment: Doh! Try CURTIME() instead of NOW().